# How to efficiently make a certain kind of dictionary modification multiple times?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as `{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'VOL-18fd3f81-b69e-47a8-8759-3e04abac962d'}`

and I want to have the output as `{{'Name' : 'VOL-18fd3f81-b69e-47a8-8759-3e04abac962d'}`.

Comment: What have your tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done by retrieving the value of `Key` and `Value`.

```
x = {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'VOL-18fd3f81-b69e-47a8-8759-3e04abac962d'}
newDict = {x['Key']:x['Value']}
#or newDict = {x.get('Key'):x.get('Value')} is None may occur
```

output

```
{'Name': 'VOL-18fd3f81-b69e-47a8-8759-3e04abac962d'}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have more than 70 such key values to convert, that is my challenge

Comment: Ok, you should have shared that in your question

Answer (score -1):

Nothing to do on it. Just write this dictionary and then just retrieve it. Your required value will be come.

```
dict1={'Name':'VOL-18fd3f81-b69e-47a8-8759-3e04abac962d'}

print(
dict1
)
# Here your key is 'Name' and the value is 'VOL-18fd3f81-b69e-47a8-8759-3e04abac962d'
```

output: `{'Name': 'VOL-18fd3f81-b69e-47a8-8759-3e04abac962d'}`

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, but I have more than 70 such key values to convert, that is my challenge

Comment: @user11730572: You need to edit your question and show more than one conversion (because all keys in a dictionary have to be unique).